Python logging in shared functions called by multiple main programs
I have reviewed this, but it doesn't seem to address what I'm asking here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727420/using-logging-in-multiple-modules
I want to have multiple programs call the same shared function, and I want the logging of the function to basically "inherit" from the calling program.
Let's say I have ProgramA.  It sets up a logger using console and file logging handlers (let's say it goes to ./log/ProgramA.log and console logging.
So when I want to log something, I do this:

    logger.info("SQL: query=" + query )


It imports a common library, for example:

from ProxyFunctions import check_website_status_with_proxy

Then to call that I do:

result = check_website_status_with_proxy(url)


My question is should I pass the logger to all function in which I want logging, like this?

result = check_website_status_with_proxy(url, logger)


So when ProgramA calls the common function the log will go to ProgramA.log.
But then later when ProgramB calls the same function, it will go to ProgramB.log.
Then what if program C wants to call it, and doesn't have logging?  I should pass None, and check for that in the function?


My question is should I pass the logger to all function in which I want logging, like this?

Assuming you are using the standard logging facilities of Python (import logging), then you should not pass your loggers as argument to functions you call.
Instead, the package or module should create loggers of its own, using a name that clearly identifies the package or module. This name should also be documented, so that the authors of ProgramA and ProgramB can filter or redirect the logging from your package as they need.
Your package or module should not do any configuration of the logging system, with the possible exception of adding a NullHandler to the package's top-level logging object if you want to suppress all logging output for programs like ProgramC that don't configure the logging system.
See also https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library

Thanks, I've added my sample code to test your answer.

The null object pattern is a good fit. Create a log object that supports all the logging methods your library needs except... it does nothing when invoked. You have a couple of options available to adapt this to your code:

Force callers to pass the "null logger" object.
Check for None in every function of your library and assign the "null logger" if need be.

As a library maintainer, I would prefer option one. Declare that your code requires a logger, and offload this responsibility to callers. This is viable if you can change the calling code. I would only consider option 2 of I couldn't modify calling code, or if the code changes would be too widespread and risky. If you are dealing with a legacy codebase, you could create delegate functions that pass a null logger so you only need to update imports without touching the calling code otherwise. This introduces a maintenance headache, and would be my least preferable option.
A "null logger" doesn't need to be complicated. Callers can simply pass Logger.none() where the Logger class exists in your library, giving you control of what this do-nothing logger does.
check_website_status_with_proxy(url, Logger.none())


I'm not confident enough with Python to list this in the main part of my answer, but you might be able to specify default arguments for the logger:
def foo(a, b, c, logger = Logger.none())

That would give you the best of both worlds.

Just be careful if Logger.none() returns a mutable object, as all invocations of foo that don't provide an explicit logger will use the same (long-lived) logger, rather than receiving its own "fresh" null logger.

@chepner: the purpose of Logger.none() is to return an object that does nothing. If the object is mutable in some way, I don't see how it would really fit the Null Object Pattern.

I've tried tests of this, and I can't get Logger.none() to compile and cannot find any references to it.

I've added my sample code to test your answer.

Here is code that demonstrates my understanding of the other posted answers.
The main differences in styles to me are:

add_two_numbers - we have to build and pass a logger, but then the log gets written intertwined with that of the calling program, which could be a big advantage in debugging

multiple_two_numbers - no logger passed, so it builds it's own.  I'm assuming code below is in 'TestModule.py' and the caller module or logger filename is "'TestModuleCaller.log'.  Thus you get two trace files, all the functions go to TestModule.log (if you set them up that way), and that would be a separate trace file from tTestModulerCaller.log


I could find no documentation on Logger.none() and could not get it working. However, see second code below - maybe that's what they meant.

import logging
from CommonFunctions import standard_logging

# Testing different ways of logging in modules (shared functions)

def add_two_numbers(x, y, logger):
    logger.info("Start add_two_numbers:  x=" + str(x) + " y=" + str(y))
    sum = x + y
    logger.info("sum=" + str(sum))
    return sum

def multiply_two_numbers(x, y):
    log_file = 'TestModule.log'
    logger = standard_logging(
        log_file, arg_max_megabytes=1, arg_backup_count=2)
    logger.info("Start multiply_two_numbers:  x=" + str(x) + " y=" + str(y))
    product = x + y
    logger.info("sum=" + str(product))
    return product


if __name__ == "__main__":

    log_file = 'TestModuleCallingProgram.log'
    logger = standard_logging(
        log_file, arg_max_megabytes=1, arg_backup_count=2)

    logger.info("Start testing logger passed to function ")
    result = add_two_numbers(5,6, logger)
    logger.info("End  demo 1")

    logger.info("Start testing logger not passed to function ")
    result = multiply_two_numbers(5,6)
    logger.info("End  demo 2")

    #logger.info("Start testing pass none logger in function  ")
    #result = add_two_numbers(5,6, Logger.none())
    #logger.info("End  demo 3")


In the TestModule.py, you can define a function like this:
def add_two_numbers(x, y, logger=None):
    logger.info("Start add_two_numbers:  x=" + str(x) + " y=" + str(y))
    sum = x + y
    logger.info("sum=" + str(sum))
    return sum

In this case, logger is an optional parameter that is set to None.
However, I can still do logger.info without errors, and no trace created, which would be the desired result.
So if caller passes a good logger it uses, if caller passes no arguments without the new logger that was added; the function runs fine, just doesn't do the logging.
FYI, this is my standard_logging routine, so I don't have to repeat it in each program.
def standard_logging(arg_filename, arg_max_megabytes, arg_backup_count):

    logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    # logger = logging.getLogger()

    # Centralize Logging here:
    log_path = r'c:\Users\All Users\WebsiteGarden\Logs'
    log_file = os.path.join(log_path, arg_filename)
    if not os.path.exists(log_path):
        os.makedirs(log_path)

    # Create a file handler to write logs to a file
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file,
                                       maxBytes=arg_max_megabytes*1024*1024,
                                       backupCount=arg_backup_count)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    file_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

    # Create a stream handler to print logs to the console
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # You can set the desired log level for console output
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)

    # Add the handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    return logger


Logger.none() is not a standard Python function. You would need to implement your own logger class with that method. If you need help applying this design technique, post on StackOverflow. This community focuses on software design problems rather than concrete coding issues. I think this would be a good fit for SO, though.

I think I posted on StackOverflow and maybe it got moved here, not sure.
